# Powershell script to automate IIS - ERROR: Could not generate audit log

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

I'm trying to automate the IIS single website stop/start by using the following script, however after running it I got the error: ERROR: Could not generate audit log and it doesn't perform the action.

```html
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "SystemOperator"))
{
sesudo -do IIS
sesudo -do Import-Module WebAdministration
$websiteName = "WebsiteName"
sesudo -do Stop-WebSite $websiteName
}
```

Any idea of what we can do here or why we even face this output? Also, if there's something you notice wrong in the script, any advice is more than welcome. Thanks

Comment: "why we even face this output", because you use a third party `sesudo` utility which is not provided by Microsoft. Ask its vendor for assistance.

Comment: I was not aware of that, I'm just starting with Powershell, so is there then a different command to elevate permissions? Thank you for the answer before :)